# Detect firestore errors

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

so i want a way to be able to detect this error inside my javascript code

@firebase/firestore: Firestore (7.19.1): FirebaseError: [code=resource-exhausted]: Quota exceeded.

i see it in the console , but the catch can't get it nor in try nor in then :/

```
try {
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "****VHhbGqI",
    authDomain: "****m-sum-235202.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://**'' '' m-sum-235202.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "premium-sum-235202",
    storageBucket: "***'' '' 02.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "428499848193",
    appId: "1:*******8193:web:520bc61504450a2e458400"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
console.log('daq')

console.log('daq2')
firebase.firestore().collection('testf').doc('test1').set({"zack9": firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)} , {merge: true }).then((data) => { alert(data) }).catch((error) => { alert('te') })
console.log('daq9')
} catch(error) {
console.log('daqaa')
console.log(error)
}

// tried this too

async function zack () {
try {
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "×**'' *****BHuNxsY5VHhbGqI",
    authDomain: "*'' '' '202.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://***' '' eio.com",
    projectId: "*****sum-235202",
    storageBucket: "**'*' '202.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "**' *848193",
    appId: "1:428499848193:web:****20bc61504450a2e458400"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
console.log('daq')

console.log('daq2')
await firebase.firestore().collection('test').doc('test1').set({"zack9": firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)} , {merge: true })
console.log('daq9')
} catch(error) {
console.log('daqaa')
console.log(error)
}
}
zack()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to track via code, errors related to quotas. As mentioned in the official documentation, related to pricing - accessible [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) - this information is only available via Console, as you mentioned, where you can track how much of your quota has already being used.

Considering that you are reaching a quota exceeded error, I would recommend you to give it a try limiting how much of reads and writes you will be doing to your database - actually, you would need to restrict any of the points from pricing that can cause you this error - so you avoid this type of error. There is a lot of ways to achieve, as using `limit()` method to restrict your calls, you can perform more specific queries to return less results, being more accurate on the information returned, etc. I would recommend you to take a look at this tutorial [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/firestoreliving/), for good examples on this.

In addition to that, you can always create a Feature Request on [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=530136&template=0), for availation about implementing this in the future.

Comment: That sad , i know how i work arround the data and that i will rarely reach the quota , it's just something i wanted to set on my web app ( display a message like " Please check Us again in 24 Hours " ) well i guess i will have to edit that firebase-firestore.js  and make it's change my state js file when there is a quota , that shouldn't be against the TOS right ?

Comment: Hi @ZackHeisenberg sure, I understand your point. I do think that it's worth it to raise a feature request, since this would be nice to have. Besides that, that's good question, if it goes against the TOS. I would recommend you to check the terms [here](https://cloud.google.com/terms/), to confirm.